# Restore snapshot to another DC server using elasticsearch-curator

Tags: elasticsearch, restore, snapshot, elasticsearch-curator

I need to keep elasticsearch-data in sync within 3 server using elasticsearch-curator. All I want to update data on one server and others update themselves using snapshot and restore method.
I was able to create snapshot using curator on first server but couldn't restore it on another.

Snapshot
While taking snapshot Host entry in curator.yml is like hosts: ["localhost"] on Server 1. I can easily restore it on Server 1 itself.

But, the problem arise when I try to restore it on Server 2
Host entry in curator.yml is like hosts: ["localhost","Server 1 IP"]
It generates error message:

```
2017-02-27 10:39:58,927 INFO      Preparing Action ID: 1, "restore"
2017-02-27 10:39:59,145 INFO      Trying Action ID: 1, "restore": Restore all indices in the most recent curator-* snapshot with state SUCCESS.  Wait for the restore to complete before continuing.  Do not skip the repository filesystem access check.  Use the other options to define the index/shard settings for the restore. 
2017-02-27 10:39:59,399 INFO      Restoring indices "['test_sec']" from snapshot: curator-20170226143036 
2017-02-27 10:39:59,409 ERROR     Failed to complete action: restore.  <class 'curator.exceptions.FailedExecution'>: Exception encountered.  Rerun with loglevel DEBUG and/or check Elasticsearch logs for more information. Exception: TransportError(500, u'snapshot_restore_exception', u'[all_index:curator-20170226143036]snapshot does not exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of related to the answer at [how to restore elasticsearch indices from S3 to blank cluster using curator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075667/how-to-restore-elasticsearch-indices-from-s3-to-blank-cluster-using-curator)

> How did you add the repository to the original (source) cluster? You need to use the exact same steps to add the repository to the new (target) cluster. Only then will the repository be readable by the new cluster.

Without more information, it's harder to pinpoint, but the `snapshot does not exist` message seems clear in this regard.  It indicates that the repository is not the same shared file system as the source cluster.